# JFreeChart proper zoom behaviour between passed java points

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

Assume that I have a **JFreeChart** 's line chart with points **(0,0)** and **(3,3)**. So the line from (0,0) to (3,3) is shown. However when I zoom **X-Axis** so that to see the data between **x=1** and **x=2** no data (no line) is shown.

The problem occurs for me in two cases:

```
JFreeChart chart = org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("Example",
                "", "test", null, false, true, false);
```

and for:

```
JFreeChart chart = org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory.createXYStepChart
                    ("Example", "", "test", null,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
```

However in the second additionally I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requires xLow < xHigh.
    at org.jfree.chart.renderer.RendererUtilities.findLiveItemsLowerBound(RendererUtilities.java:76)
    at org.jfree.chart.renderer.RendererUtilities.findLiveItems(RendererUtilities.java:261)
    at org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot.render(XYPlot.java:3845)
    at org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot.draw(XYPlot.java:3389)
    at org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart.draw(JFreeChart.java:1237)
    at org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel.paintComponent(ChartPanel.java:1677)
```

The main question is:

**How can I set the renderer up to see the data (line) even if I zoom between 'passed data points'?**

Comment: Too little information. Which DataSet interface/implementation, which method used to construct the chart, etc.

Comment: @Holger I extended the question a little bit.

Comment: Did you try `createXYLineChart`?

Comment: @Holger No because step chart and timeseries chart are needed. However I expect similar problem for 'plain' XY line chart.

Comment: Oh it surely makes a difference. XYLineChart will have a NumberAxis as domain axis the other two will have a DateAxis. And it’s the domain axis which controls the behavior you described. Maybe there’s a reason for the “step” in “createXYStepChart”…

Comment: I'm going to check if there is a bug here.  What version of JFreeChart are you using?  Is it 1.0.15?

Comment: @DavidGilbert Checked in 1.0.14 and in 1.0.15. In both the problem occurs.

Comment: So with data (0, 0) and (3, 3), I see this exception when zooming in...I think it is to do with the date axis (as @Holger suggested), because the x-values here will be interpreted as milliseconds since 1-Jan-1970 so we are looking at a very small range of x-values...and zooming in most likely leaves us with an axis range with 0 length (because of some rounding).  This is, of course, a bug in JFreeChart...I will look some more.

Comment: @DavidGilbert It would be great because this simple case can be crucial in our decision about using JFreeChart. Many thanks.

Comment: Revision [2910](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/2910/) is my proposed fix for JFreeChart 1.0.16.

Comment: @DavidGilbert Looks very good. The code is a bit redundant in both cases (isInverted and not - the only difference between them is how you count adjStart and adjEnd). But anyway looks good and many thanks for the quick fix. When the release of 1.0.16 is planned?